# Simple VLAN Trunking between 2 switches

Tags: networking, vlan

I am trying to set up a connection between 2 buildings. In building 1 I have the following:

> 1. Network 1 192.168.2.0/24
> 2. Network 2 192.168.3.0/24
> 3. Network 3 192.168.0.0/24
> 4. Network 4 192.168.180.0/22

All the above are just different subnets on different cables. Let's say I run one cable to building 2. I have a Cisco SG300-10 in each building and I would like to plug all 4 into the first switch, and by creating port based VLANs trunk them together, connect the 2 switches with the cable that runs across the 2 buildings and patch in in building 2.

I have created 4 VLANs using the web interface.
In the port VLAN membership of each switch I have

> GE1    Trunk   1UP 1UP
>   GE2    Access  2UP 2UP
>   GE3    Access  3UP 3UP
>   GE4    Access  180UP   180UP
>   GE5    Access  10UP    10UP
>   GE6    Trunk   1UP 1UP
>   GE7    Trunk   1UP 1UP
>   GE8    Trunk   1UP 1UP
>   GE9    Trunk   1UP 1UP
>   GE10   Trunk   1UP, 2T, 3T, 10T, 180T  1UP, 2T, 3T, 10T, 180T

The cable that runs between the 2 buildings is on port 10 on each switch. I plug all the cables in building 1 and then when I go to building 2, I dont get an IP on port 2,3,4 or 5. But if I connect a cable on port 1 and on port 10 on each switch, then I get an IP in building 2. Can anyone tell me what I am missing? I had the same setup some years ago with Netgear switches and it was working fine.

Thanks

Comment: In building 1, what are ports 2-5 on teh SG300 connected to physically? If you unplug the cable that's going into GE2 on the SG300 and plug it into your laptop, do you get an IP?

Comment: Yes, I get an IP. GE2 is plugged in to a switch on the 192.168.2.0/24 network and that cable gives me an IP in that range

Comment: It's gotta be something silly - this should work. On other cisco switches, you must create the vlan on each switch or use VTP. Have vlans 2, 3, 10 and 180 been created on both switches? I know they're being passed by the trunk ports but they need to exist on the switches themselves also.

Comment: both vlans have been created on both switches. They are exactly the same.